# getting a 404 error while clicking on a article

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am building my first CodeIgniter website and I am conquering a problem that seems to be hard to solve..

When I click on a article to read it I keep getting a 404 page. ( not found )

the link that I get is as follows

index.php/articles/articlename

In my controller I have the following for the view part

```
    public function view($slug) {
    $data['article_item'] = $this->articles_model->get_article($slug);

    if (empty($data['article_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['article_item']['title'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('articles/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/side', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

As you see it has to include the view.php in the articles directory

In my router I have the following

```
    $route['articles/(:any)'] = 'articles/view/$1';
$route['articles/create'] = 'articles/create';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['gallery'] = 'gallery';
$route['articles'] = 'articles';
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Just to be sure I have posted every relevant stuff here is the link that I create

```
<a href="articles/<?php echo $article_item['slug'] ?>" class="button">Read more</a>
```

and the model

```
    <?php
class Articles_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_article($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('articles');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('articles', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here..

Comment: Maybe `$data['article_item']` is empty? `var_dump` it.

Comment: hmm I tried but somehow I don't get anything but a 404 page as output..

Comment: When you tested, did you comment out your `show_404()` call?

Comment: Yes I Did, The problem was that my page for the articles was in the common pages directory so the router took the wrong file. I solved it now and it works

Comment: just for the record that's an inefficient way to be doing the templating. Create a new view called template.php load the other 4 views there, then just pass what you want to be the main view as a parameter in $data.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the function name in your link.

Your URL should be: index.php/articles/view/articlename

The first part in your URL after index.php is the name of your Class and the second part is the name of your function and then your input values